# UpdateProgress Covers Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

Is there any way to get an updateprogress to entirely cover an updatepanel ?

(Asp.net .net 4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<asp:updateprogress associatedupdatepanelid="UpdatePanel3" 
    id="updateProgress" runat="server">
    <progresstemplate>
        <div id="progressBackgroundFilter"></div>
        <div id="processMessage"> Loading...<br /><br />
             <img alt="Loading" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>
    </progresstemplate>
</asp:updateprogress> 

#progressBackgroundFilter {
position:fixed; 
top:0px; 
bottom:0px; 
left:0px;
right:0px;
overflow:hidden; 
padding:0; 
margin:0; 
background-color:#000; 
filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
opacity:0.5; 
z-index:1000; 
}
#processMessage { 
position:fixed; 
top:30%; 
left:43%;
padding:10px; 
width:14%; 
z-index:1001; 
background-color:#fff;
border:solid 1px #000;
```

Comment: This code is useful if you want to entirely cover the page, but it doesn't solve the OP's specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the [FlanAjaxControls](http://flanajaxcontrols.codeplex.com/) to only overlay the UpdatePanel.